# Agent 2D not showing, 3D ok

Tags: anylogic

Upgraded to 8.3.2. with the new dae files.  2D not showing in main and when I run the model. the object is there but blank. 3D shows up when I run the model but only in 3D.

Comment: If you try using one of the example models, does the 2D stuff show up?

Comment: No, the same thing happens with the example models.    I will try to post some images but new to this so ....

Comment: Sounds like not a model problem. Next comes an inevitable question: Have you tried re-installing? Also, do you have the maintenance on your license? If so, you can ask for assistance from AnyLogic homebase. Also, you could try returning back to an earlier version of AnyLogic to test it out.